# Getting Rid of Scientific Notation on A Cell with Text using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of data that contains large numbers formatted as "General" (this is the default setting from a system report that gets automatically emailed to me). From this large number, I have to add some text in front of it, which I did by using VBA to automate the process because I have hundreds of rows of data. The problem now is that the result is a mixture of text and scientific notation and I have no idea how to fix it. I've tried converting the original data from "General" to "Text" and this still did not fix the problem. I've also tried putting an apostrophe in front of the large number, but again I still run into the same problem. Can anyone help me come up with a VBA code that will fix this?

[image]

Comment: Set the cell format (or the column) to text BEFORE you enter the large number into the cell. I just tested it, and then a formula will concatenate them easily. `=B1 & A1`

Comment: Ahhh, so simple! Worked like a charm! Thank you!!!